# How to access loaded data within an entity framework model's partial class

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I'm creating a partial class to add some business logic to my `Schedule` entity model, which is already mapped to a database table. Here's my partial class:

```
Partial Public Class Schedule

    Public WithEvents previousSchedules As SortableBindingList(Of schedule)

    Public Sub New()
        previousSchedules = getPreviousSchedules()
    End Sub

    Private Function getPreviousSchedules()
        Return contract.schedules.Where(Function(s) s.sched_seq < sched_seq)
    End Function

End Class
```

`contract` is a (parent) property of a schedule. The problem is, when the schedule is instantiated and `getPreviousSchedules` is executed, `contract` is `Nothing`. I assume entity framework is making a shell object to pass around, then asynchronously loading the data.

But how do I know when the data has loaded, so I can work with it?

Comment: Are you creating a new instance of Schedule or are you retrieving the data from EF? Better for you to give a condition to check if previous is null or not, if it is, return null for now.

Comment: I have my entities model and I'm doing something like: `return context.schedules`. I can certainly check if contract is null, but how can I run the sub again when I get the data?

Comment: You can create a property for `previousSchedules` and check if it's null, then call `getPreviousSchedules()`

Comment: But again, when should I call getPreviousSchedules? I want the data as soon as it's ready - when is that?

Answer (score 0):

Using a property solves this problem:

```
Public ReadOnly Property previousSchedules As SortableBindingList(Of schedule)
    Get
        Dim list = New SortableBindingList(Of schedule)

        Dim scheds = contract.schedules.Where(Function(s) s.sched_seq < sched_seq).ToList
        For Each sched As schedule In scheds
            list.Add(sched)
        Next

        Return list
    End Get
End Property
```